# RODBC loses precision of numeric columns with sqlSave to MS SQL (and fails on Date)

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc, significant-digits

Why is RODBC losing precision of my numeric column when saving to ms sql with sqlSave?

## Numbers

In R, i create the following dataframe with a numerical column. They might seem rounded already, but that is a printing issue, they are not rounded.

```
>test <- data.frame(
          id=c(1,2,3),
          numbers=c(12345678.90,12345678.91,12345678.92)
          )
> str(test)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ id     : num  1 2 3
 $ numbers: num  12345679 12345679 12345679
> test$numbers==123456789
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Saving it to the database, seems to indicate that some precision is lost:

```
> dbconn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};server=HOSTNAME\\SQL2014;database=test_db;trusted_connection=true")
> sqlSave(dbconn, test, fast=F, verbose=T)
Query: CREATE TABLE "test"  ("rownames" varchar(255), "id" float, "numbers" float)
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "numbers" ) VALUES ( '1', 1, 12345679 )
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "numbers" ) VALUES ( '2', 2, 12345679 )
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "numbers" ) VALUES ( '3', 3, 12345679 )
```

By fetching the dataframe back from the database we can verify that the precision is indeed lost:

```
> test2<-sqlFetch(dbconn, "test")
> test2
  id  numbers
1  1 12345679
2  2 12345679
3  3 12345679
> test2$numbers==12345679
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

float seems to be the correct column type, so is there a way to force rodbc to use an alternative to character conversion? Even the default as.character would have worked.

```
> as.character(test$numbers)
[1] "12345678.9"  "12345678.91" "12345678.92"
```

## Dates

Date class columns result in ms sql columns of type float, causing incorrect values being stored:

```
> test <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),date=as.Date(c("2014-12-21","2014-12-22","2014-12-23")))
> sqlSave(dbconn, test, fast=F, verbose=T)
Query: CREATE TABLE "test"  ("rownames" varchar(255), "id" float, "date" float)
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date" ) VALUES ( '1', 1, 2014-12-21 )
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date" ) VALUES ( '2', 2, 2014-12-22 )
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date" ) VALUES ( '3', 3, 2014-12-23 )

> test2<-sqlFetch(dbconn, "test")
> test2
   id date
 1  1 1981
 2  2 1980
 3  3 1979
```

As the date is interpreted as a formula:

```
> 2014-12-21
[1] 1981
```

---

```
> packageVersion("RODBC")
[1] ‘1.3.10’
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code of RODBC there seems to be internal calls to unlist within as.matrix.dataframe, which could explain this issue:

```
> unlist(list(test))
     id1      id2      id3 numbers1 numbers2 numbers3 
       1        2        3 12345679 12345679 12345679 '
```

My best guest would be to work around RODBC and take control of both the to-character conversion as the varType logic.

Logical columns are interpreted as being varchar, which we could easily change into BIT's

```
sqlSave2<-function(dbconn, dat, tablename = NULL, ...){
  # get the name of the variable passed as dat, taken from sqlSave implementation
  if (is.null(tablename)) 
    tablename <- if (length(substitute(dat)) == 1) 
      as.character(substitute(dat))
  else as.character(substitute(dat)[[2L]])
  if (length(tablename) != 1L) 
    stop(sQuote(tablename), " should be a name")
    varTypes <- sapply(dat, function(x){
    if(is.numeric(x)){
      "float"
      }else if(is.factor(x)|is.character(x)){
        paste0("[varchar](",max(nchar(as.character(x))),")")
        } else if(is.logical(x)){"BIT"} else if("Date"%in%class(x)) {
          "date"
          } else if ("POSIXt"%in%class(x)){
            "smalldatetime"
            }else{NA}})# let RODBC determine
  varTypes <- varTypes[!is.na(varTypes)]
  dat2<-as.data.frame(sapply(dat, function(x){
    if(is.numeric(x)){
      x2<-sprintf("%.15e",x)
      if(sum(is.na(x))>0)
        x2[is.na(x)]<-NA
      x2
    } else if(is.logical(x)){
      x2<-rep(0,length(x))
      x2[!is.na(x) & x==T]<-1
      if(sum(is.na(x))>0)
        x2[is.na(x)] <- NA
      x2
      } else as.character(x)
  }))
  sqlSave(dbconn, dat2, tablename, fast=FALSE, varTypes=varTypes, ...)
}
```

With the following dataframe

```
> test <- data.frame(
    id=c(123456789.12,123456789.23,123456789.23), 
    date=as.Date(c("2014-12-21","2014-12-22","2014-12-23")),
    datetime=as.POSIXlt(c("2014-12-21 10:00","2014-12-22 11:00","2014-12-23 12:00")))
> str(test)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id      : num  1.23e+08 1.23e+08 1.23e+08
 $ date    : Date, format: "2014-12-21" "2014-12-22" "2014-12-23"
 $ datetime: POSIXct, format: "2014-12-21 10:00:00" "2014-12-22 11:00:00" "2014-12-23 12:00:00"
```

We get instead of the default:

```
> sqlSave(dbconn, test, fast=F, verbose=T)
Query: CREATE TABLE "test"  ("rownames" varchar(255), "id" float, "date" float, "datetime" float)
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date", "datetime" ) VALUES ( '1', 123456789, 2014-12-21, 2014-12-21 10:00:00 )
Error in sqlSave(dbconn, test, fast = F, verbose = T) : 
  42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '10'.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date", "datetime" ) VALUES ( '1', 123456789, 2014-12-21, 2014-12-21 10:00:00 )'
```

The following:

```
> sqlSave2(dbconn, test)
Query: CREATE TABLE "test"  ("rownames" varchar(255), "id" float, "date" date, "datetime" smalldatetime)
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date", "datetime" ) VALUES ( '1', 1.234567891200000e+08, N'2014-12-21', '2014-12-21 10:00:00' )
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date", "datetime" ) VALUES ( '2', 1.234567892300000e+08, N'2014-12-22', '2014-12-22 11:00:00' )
Query: INSERT INTO "test" ( "rownames", "id", "date", "datetime" ) VALUES ( '3', 1.234567892300000e+08, N'2014-12-23', '2014-12-23 12:00:00' )
```

With the following verification:

```
> test2<-sqlFetch(dbconn, "test")
> test2
         id       date            datetime
1 123456789 2014-12-21 2014-12-21 10:00:00
2 123456789 2014-12-22 2014-12-22 11:00:00
3 123456789 2014-12-23 2014-12-23 12:00:00
> str(test2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id      : num  1.23e+08 1.23e+08 1.23e+08
 $ date    : Factor w/ 3 levels "2014-12-21","2014-12-22",..: 1 2 3
 $ datetime: POSIXct, format: "2014-12-21 10:00:00" "2014-12-22 11:00:00" "2014-12-23 12:00:00"
> test2$id==123456789
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```